# ListView in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to get a `ListView` working in an android `ViewPager` `Fragment`. This code I have so far however causes the app to crash - I'm not sure why!

```
public class DirectoryFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_directory, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        String[] values = new String[] {"Viewer 1",
                                        "Viewer 2",
                                        "Viewer 3"
                                       };

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get NPE on `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` because `listView` is not initialised correctly.

You need to change:

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.list);
```

and make sure you have `list` id in `fragment_directory`.

Your view is `rootView`, so you need that for finding `ListView`.

**//Edit**

please change

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

but your code is correct, problem is some where else.

Comment: Great! The app no longer crashes, but the ListView is blank.

Comment: ask new question with more details, because this must be worked and new problem is not related to this post, your code is fine, you must post activity class and fragment class for use to debug your code